# How to import a text file with multiple layouts into SQL with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, text-files, metadata, ssis-2014

I'm fairly new to SSIS, any help would be much appreciated!

I need to import a comma delimited text file.
The rows in the file have different layouts.
The value of the first column specifies the layout.

For example:

Layout 1: Name, Surname, Age, ID

Layout 2: ID, Salary

So column names and data types differ completely.

Is there a way to import such a file without using a script task in SSIS?

Comment: It's a while since I used SSIS but can you not split the file into many files based on distinct column 1 , add headers and then import them?

Comment: what is the SQL table structure?

Comment: @Hadi there are 9 different types of layouts.
I can't share the specifics.

Comment: @P.Salmon that is my next plan.
Wanted to know if there is a better way first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flat file source from the SSIS toolbox/Other sources. Check  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/flat-file-connection-manager for more information
Edited: After you changed your question, I undrestood better. Script task is the only solution, as you have to build a logic.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    // Create the StreamReader object to read the input file
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(this.Variables.vInputFilename);

    // Loop through the file to read each line
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        // Read one line
        string line = reader.ReadLine();

        // Break the file apart into atomic elements
        string[] items = line.Split('|');

        /*
            Each line should match one of three record types. When matched to
            the correct type, a new row in that output will be created and the
            columns from the file will be written to the appropriate output cols
        */

        // Record type 1 is Manager
        if (items[0] == "Layout 1")
        {
            OutputBuffer0.AddRow();

        }

        // Layout 2
        else if (items[0] == "Layout 2")
        {
            OutputBuffer1.AddRow();

        }
    }
}
```

Then based on the output you connect the relevant tables.Let me know if it works :)

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem, thank you for trying.
I need to know how to change file layout mappings on the fly

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.
For someone who is more SQL and BI oriented, would you mind telling me how to proceed from there?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: An example here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/66136/.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I got a person with C# skills to help we with a script component.
file gets split into multiple files and then imported from there...